# How to determine output path directory for trimesh.exchange.ply.export_ply?

Tags: python, export, meshlab, ply-file-format, trimesh

I am working with datasets of ply files. Eventually, I need to export the ply files in a separate directory.

Now, if I use the function trimesh.exchange.ply.export_ply, I cant seem to understand how to set the directory where to export the meshes. I have read the documentation but it didn't have any mention on how to set output path

```
    mesh = trimesh.load("file.ply") 

    #print(mesh.volume)

    trimesh.exchange.ply.export_ply(mesh, encoding='ascii') #How to set output directory?
```

Alternatively I am using mesh.export(path) which does successfully export files but with some files it gives an error
[when opened in meshlab or any other editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbQAp.png)

Any suggestions on how to export as ply files?

Answer (score 0):

`trimesh.exchange.ply.export_ply()` produce byte array. You can write it to file you want like this:

```py
result = trimesh.exchange.ply.export_ply(mesh, encoding='ascii')
output_file = open(your_path, "wb+")
output_file.write(result)
output_file.close()
```

### Demo

Worked fine =) I used available free [scan](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/roomscan-lidar-ply-sample-ff44fcea495a4a9d9e5e6bf76ef89464) as input file:

[image]